# Poisson regression model - how to add regression line with specific value of coefficient?

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression

So, I have my poisson regression model: (mvdiff = market value diff, participations = participations in world cup)

```
mod <- glm(goals~participations+MVdiff, family = poisson)
plot(MVdiff, jitter(goals , 0.2), pch=17)
```

Now I would like to include a regression function line into my plot: as a function of MVdiff, with the value of 9.2 for participations (as in 9.2 is the mean of the participations in the world cup).

Here my try:

```
curve(exp(mod$coefficients[1]+mod$coefficients[2]*x+9.2+mod$coefficients[3]),
      lwd=3,col="red",add=TRUE)
```

But this doesn't quite work out. Is there a way to properly add the value of 9.2 into my coefficient variable participation?

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the model output at a fixed value of an independent variable, use `predict` with the value of that variable fixed:

```r
pred_df <- data.frame(MVdiff = seq(-1500, 1500), participations = 9.2)
predictions <- predict(mod, newdata = pred_df , type = "response")
```

Now plot this as a line over your data:

```r
plot(df$MVdiff, jitter(df$goals , 0.2), pch = 16) 
lines(pred_df$MVdiff, predictions, col = "red")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, so I had to create my own for the example with the following code:

```r
set.seed(123)

participations <- rpois(500, 9.2)
MVdiff         <- rnorm(500, 0, 600)
goals          <- rpois(500, 1 + MVdiff/3000)
```